# Passing an array of structs to a function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

I would like learn how to pass, by reference, an array of structs to the `second function` called/executed from within the `first function`. My goal is to  modify/change the contents of arbitrary struct from the `second function` **only**. The code below works, but, unfortunately, does not do exactly what I want to achieve. I would to have access to arbitrary struct within `second function`. In other words, I would like to process all structs (using `for` loop) within `second function` by calling/executing `first function` in `main` only **once** and not using `for` loop.

The `second function`, in the code below, is named `passByReference_inner`.

**array_of_struct.h :**

```
struct card
{
    int face;
    int nose;
};

typedef struct card HEAD ;

/* prototype */
extern void passByReference(HEAD **c);      /* first function */
extern void passByReference_inner(HEAD *c); /* second function */
```

**first function:** (passByReference)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "array_of_struct.h"

void passByReference(HEAD **c)
{
    passByReference_inner (*c);   /* second function */
}
```

**second function:** (passByReference_inner)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "array_of_struct.h"

void passByReference_inner(HEAD *c)
{
    c->face = (c->face) + 1000;
    c->nose = (c->nose) + 2000;
}
```

**main:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "array_of_struct.h"

int main(void)
{
    int             i;
    static HEAD     c[12];
    static HEAD *cptr[12];

    for ( i = 0; i < 12; i++ )
    {
        c[i].face = i + 30;
        c[i].nose = i + 60; 
        cptr[i]   = &c[i];
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < 12; i++ )
    {
        passByReference(&cptr[i]);  /* first function */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wish all questions were like this one...

Comment: the C language cannot pass by reference, only by value; however, it can pass a pointer.

Comment: in main(), the variable 'cptr' and all usage can be completely replaced with references to '&c[i]'

Comment: in main() this line: 'cptr[i]   = &c[i]' does nothing and can be eliminated

Comment: in the code, the number '12' is a 'magic' number that occurs several places in the code.  that number should be defined by #define MAX_COUNT (12) then MAX_COUNT used in all places where '12' is currently being used.

Comment: @user3629249 TNX+ for comments. Yes, I could implement all of your suggestions... but ... my intentions was (and still is) to make the code as readable as possible for other beginners like me.
Re 'by reference/value': I am using what I learned from the net. [by reference](http://goo.gl/pLIxe9) [by value](http://cprogrammingexpert.com/C/Tutorial/functions/pass_by_value.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second function is correct.

A pointer to the first element of an array is effectively the same thing as the pointer to an array itself.

What you should do is

```
void passByReference_inner(HEAD *c, size_t n)
{
}
```

So, you'll pass the pointer to the first element of the array, and the number of elements in the array, something like this:

```
passByReference(c, sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]));
```

This will pass the pointer to the first element of the `c` array, and the number of elements in the array, to passByReference_inner(). sizeof(c) is the size of the entire array in bytes. sizeof(c[0]) is the size of an element in the array. So, if, for example, each struct is 10 bytes long (just an example), and you have an array of 12 structs, the size of the entire array is 120 bytes, and this calculates the value 120/10=12, the number of elements in the array, automatically.

When you use the name of an array object, in C/C++ that automatically becomes a pointer to the first element of the array.

In your function, you can work with the array in the following manner:

```
void passByReference_inner(HEAD *c, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        HEAD *p=c+i;

        // p is now a pointer to the ith element of the array
    }
}
```

Adding an integer `n` to a pointer advances the pointer to the next `nth` element of an array. Adding an integer value to a pointer doesn't advance the pointer by this number of bytes, but by the number of bytes in the object the pointer points to, multiplied by the number you're adding (or subtracting, same thing). That makes pointer arithmetic do the right thing.

Comment: "When you use the name of an array object, in C/C++ that automatically becomes a pointer " In C++, only in a context where a pointer is expected. You *can* pass pointers or references to arrays of a given size. (In C, a pointer to an array does seem to bind to any old pointer. I'm not sure if that is standard or a compiler extension.)

Comment: @juanchopanza there is no C++ in this question. And what is "_does seem to bind to any old pointer_" supposed to mean?

Comment: @iharob I was referring to a sentence in this answer, which mentions "C/C++" (which might suggest it applies to both languages since there is no hybrid C/C++ language). As for "... any old pointer", my phrasing is poor, but it seems in C you can say `int (*p)[2] = &a;` where `a` is an `int`. In C++ `a` would have to be an `int[2]`.

Comment: @juanchopanza No you can't, in C `a` would have to be `int[2]` too. You can compile that for sure, but at least `gcc` would issue a warning. And regarding the C/C++ thing, yes no I see that in the answer, sorry.

Comment: @iharob I am not sure of the details, but at least clang issues an error in C++, and only a warning in C (my recollection is that recent versions of gcc behave in the same way.) My understanding is that an implementation *has* to issue an error in C++. In any case, my point about the sentence in question holds.

Comment: Dear reader, please, scroll down to the fourth solution, where you can see the implementation of the Sam Varshavchik's suggestion/solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are trying to do is this

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct card
{
    int face;
    int nose;
};

typedef struct card HEAD ;

/* prototype */
void passByReference(HEAD *c, int count);      /* first function */
void passByReference_inner(HEAD *c); /* second function */

void passByReference(HEAD *c, int count)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
        passByReference_inner (&(c[i]));   /* second function */
}

void passByReference_inner(HEAD *c)
{
    c->face = (c->face) + 1000;
    c->nose = (c->nose) + 2000;
}

int main(void)
{
    int  i;
    HEAD c[12]; /* you don't need static here (do you know what static is for?) */

    for ( i = 0; i < 12; i++ )
    {
        c[i].face = i + 30;
        c[i].nose = i + 60;
    }
    /* 
     * the element count of the array is sizeof(c) / sizeof(c[0]) 
     *    (totalSizeOfArray) / (indivudualElementSizeOfArray).
     */
    passByReference(c, sizeof(c) / sizeof(c[0]));  /* first function */

    return 0;
}
```

what you should know is that arrays in [c](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/c) decay to a pointer that points to their first element when passed as parameters to functions.

Since you want to process all the structs in the second function, I don't see the need for the first function, anyway this is how you would do it then

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct card
{
    int face;
    int nose;
};

typedef struct card HEAD ;

/* prototype */
void passByReference(HEAD *const c, int count);      /* first function */
void passByReference_inner(HEAD *const c, int count); /* second function */

void passByReference(HEAD *const c, int count)
{
    passByReference_inner(c, count);   /* second function */
}

/* HEAD *const c prevents the pointer c to be changed
 * this way it will never point anywhere else.
 *
 * And you can be sure to alter the original data.
 */
void passByReference_inner(HEAD *const c, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
    {
        c[i].face = (c[i].face) + 1000;
        c[i].nose = (c[i].nose) + 2000;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int  i;
    HEAD c[12]; /* you don't need static here (do you know what static is for?) */

    for ( i = 0; i < 12; i++ )
    {
        c[i].face = i + 30;
        c[i].nose = i + 60;
    }
    /* 
     * the element count of the array is sizeof(c) / sizeof(c[0]) 
     *    (totalSizeOfArray) / (indivudualElementSizeOfArray).
     */
    passByReference(c, sizeof(c) / sizeof(c[0]));  /* first function */

    return 0;
}
```

since you are effectively passing a pointer, you alter it's contents directly in both functions the first and the second.

One more thing, you don't really need the `static` keyword, specially in `main()`, `static` keeps the value of the variable between function calls, and since `main()` will normally be called only once in the lifetime of the program... it doesn't make much sense to use `static` there.

Comment: Why would you make `HEAD` `static` if you a passing by reference?

Comment: I think OP wants the `for` loop inside of `passByReference_inner`. Doesn't really change the essence of the answer, but needs a little rearranging.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Are you confusing `static` with `const`?

Comment: @user3386109 you are right, I just re-read the question, some times I have trouble to understand english.

Comment: No problem, the wording in the question made it hard to keep track of all the functions, but your answer is good +1.

Comment: @user3386109 - No. Giving `HEAD` file scope serves no purpose here. You might as well remove the address arguments from the functions. However, remove `static` completely so `HEAD` has functions scope in `main()` then it makes sense.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin When used inside of a function, the `static` keyword doesn't give a variable file scope, it gives the variable [static](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) storage. In other words, the variable is stored in the [BSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) area, and not on the stack. You can't access `c[12]` outside of `main`, unless `main` gives you a pointer to it.

Comment: I stand corrected regarding the `static within a block`. The use of the the `static` in `main()` serves no purpose here.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Agreed that `static` serves no purpose for an array of 12 items in code targeted for a modern desktop machine.

Comment: @user3386109, (at)iharob, (at)DavidC.Rankin  tnx++ to all of you. I learned a lot from your comment's thread above

Comment: @Igor You can accept the answer that helped you the most. Check this [link](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @iharob Yes, I will 'accept' the answer which helped me the most, as soon as possible. Right now I am evaluating/implementing all solutions in the program I am writing. The original question was just greatly simplified real life case

Answer (score 0):

- The following code compiles cleanly.
- The following code moves the increment values loop
   to inside the passByReference() function.

---

```
/* 
 * Note: guard code is used in a header file
 *       so the header file can only be included once
 *       in each compilation unit 
 */

// note the inclusion of a 'guard' wrapper
// begin: array_of_struct.h file
#ifndef ARRAY_OF_STRUCT_H
#define ARRAY_OF_STRUCT_H

struct card
{
    int face;
    int nose;
};

// dont obsecure the code with useless typedef statements
//typedef struct card HEAD ;

#define MAX_CARDS (12)

/* prototype */
extern void passByReference(struct card *pCards);      /* first function */
extern void passByReference_inner(struct card *pCard); /* second function */
#endif
// end: array_of_struct.h


//first function: (passByReference), in different file

#include <stdio.h>
#include "array_of_struct.h" 

void passByReference(struct card *pCards)
{
    int i=0; // loop index

    for(i=0;i<MAX_CARDS;i++)
    {
        passByReference_inner (&pCards[i]);   /* second function */
    } // end for
} // end function: passByReference

// second function: (passByReference_inner), in different file

#include <stdio.h>
#include "array_of_struct.h"

void passByReference_inner(struct card *pCard)
{
    pCard->face = (pCard->face) + 1000;
    pCard->nose = (pCard->nose) + 2000;
} // end function: passByReference_inner

//main, in a different file

#include <stdio.h>
#include "array_of_struct.h"

int main()
{
    int i = 0; // loop index
    static struct card     cards[MAX_CARDS];

    for ( i = 0; i < MAX_CARDS; i++ )
    {
        cards[i].face = i + 30;
        cards[i].nose = i + 60;
    } // end for

    passByReference(&cards[0]);  /* first function gets ptr to whole array*/
    // could also be written as:
    // passByReference(cards);

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Answer (score 0):

I've analyzed all three solutions (iharob, user3629249, Sam Varshavchik) and came to the conclusion that Sam Varshavchik and the second solution from iharob were right on the money. The first iharob's solution and user3629249 solution are, in essence, equal. They moved `for` loop from `main` to the `first function`. The second solution of the iharob's post matches the requirements from the initial post.  Sam's solution gave me enough hints/instructions for 'how to move `for` loop from the main to the `second function` (which was, basically, what I did not know how to do it and therefore asked for help).

So, to make long story short, here is the source code which implements almost all suggestions from all contributors. The code compiles cleanly, so, beginners like me, can take it as-is and learn few details about pointer to pointer, pointer arithmetic and about array of structs.

**array_of_struct.h**  (header file)

```
#ifndef ARRAY_OF_STRUCT_H
#define ARRAY_OF_STRUCT_H

/* HEAD structure definition */
typedef struct
{
    int face;
    int nose;
} HEAD;       // end structure HEAD

#define MAX_HEADS (12)

/* prototype */
extern void passByReference(HEAD **c, size_t n);
extern void passByReference_inner(HEAD *c, size_t n);

#endif
```

**passByReference.c**  (first function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "array_of_struct.h"

void passByReference(HEAD **c, size_t n)
{
    passByReference_inner (*c, n);
}
```

**passByReference_inner.c**  (second function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "array_of_struct.h"

void passByReference_inner(HEAD *c, size_t n)
{
    int   i;
    HEAD *p;

    printf("\nPOINTER ARITHMETIC: The value of struct's  members after PASS BY REFERENCE \n");
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        p = c + i;

        p->face = (p->face) + 1000;
        p->nose = (p->nose) + 2000;
        printf("struct[%i].face = %d  \n",i, p[0].face);
        printf("struct[%i].nose = %d  \n",i, p[0].nose);
    }

    printf("\nARRAY INDEX MATH: The value of struct's  members after PASS BY REFERENCE\n");
    printf("[NOTE: structs were updated in the for loop above]\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf("struct[%i].face = %d  \n",i, c[i].face);
        printf("struct[%i].nose = %d  \n",i, c[i].nose);
    }
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "array_of_struct.h"

int main(void)
{
    int     i;
    HEAD    c[MAX_HEADS];
    HEAD   *cptr;
    size_t  n;

    n = (sizeof(c) / sizeof(c[0]);

    printf("\nINITIALIZATION of all struct's  members\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        c[i].face = i + 30;
        c[i].nose = i + 60; 
        printf("struct[%i].face = %d\n",i, c[i].face);
        printf("struct[%i].nose = %d\n",i, c[i].nose);
    }

    cptr = &c[0];
    passByReference(&cptr, n); 

    return 0;
}
```